# ffmpeg how to calculate complete frame ['I' frame ] from [ 'P' frame ]. It is conceptually correct?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get the knowledge of ffmpeg streaming video handling.

what I understood:

I get from the IPed Camaera, the frames like 'IPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPIPPPPPPP'..

Frame 'I' is a complete frame, where as frame 'P' depends on the previous either 'P' or 'I' frame which ever is the closes.

I get the frame by using   avcodec_decode_video2

```
while (av_read_frame (context, &packet) >=0)
{   
        //LOGD (" Received PACKET...DTS and PTS  %ld and %ld ", packet.pts, packet.dts);

        if(packet.stream_index == videoStreamIndex ) { 
                avcodec_decode_video2 (pCodecCtx, pFrame, &finished, &packet);
                if ( finished) {
                // Here is my frame, getting the type by av_get_picture_type_char(pFrame->pict_type).
          }
 }
```

Now, When i display just the frames that i have received, looks like whenever 'I' frame received, it displays properly,  when received 'P' frames, the image goes for a toss.

1)  We need to manually do  any calculation to convert 'P' Frame to 'I' Frame so that it can be rendered?

2) If not (1), what do i have to take care?..Does DTS/PTS calcuation do the magic here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P frame does not depend on previous P frame, it depends on previous picture. So, for example, if you have IPP, you need both I and second P to use the third P, not just the second P.

`decode_video2` does the interpolation for you and returns the images, so the reason it goes toss must be something different.

PTS/DTS tells you WHEN to show the frame, but the frames still must be valid.

Comment: Thanks George, Do i need to do still PTS/DTS Calculation if i am interested only displaying Video frame?

Comment: You need to get the PTS information from the frame which will tell yo when to show a specific frame (otherwise your video would play as fast as the device could). DTS you shouldn't care much as they're handled by FFmpeg itself.

Comment: thanks, do u have any reference, how to handle pts calculation, as it is really confusing, and no one provided concrete explanation.